# How to set multiple matrix elements at a time in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a sparse representation of a matrix M as below:

```
1 3 6

2 5 7

5 4 10
```

which means that `M[1,3]=6`, `M[2,5]=7`, and `M[5,4]=10`. If I want to generate a regular 2D matrix from this representation, is there a way to set all existing elements of this 2D matrix M at once? I don't want to go over all index pairs in a loop, because there are thousands of such pairs (although there are only 3 of them in the example above).

I tried `M[c(1,2,5),c(3,5,4)]=c(6,7,10)`, but it also sets `M[1,5]=6` and `M[1,4]=6` besides `M[1,3]=6`.

Comment: Use `M[cbind(c(1,2,5),c(3,5,4))]<-c(6,7,10)`

Comment: What @MrFlick is proposing is matrix indexing. You can use a 2 column matrix to index another matrix, column1=row index, column2=col index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "sparse" I say Matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
M <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1, 2, 5),
                  j = c(3, 5, 4),
                  x = c(6, 7, 10),
                  dims = c(5, 5))
#5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#
#[1,] . . 6  . .
#[2,] . . .  . 7
#[3,] . . .  . .
#[4,] . . .  . .
#[5,] . . . 10 .
```

If you need a base R matrix:

```
as.matrix(M)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    6    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    7
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0   10    0
```

Comment: Is there a way to give row and column names as parameters to sparseMatrix(), I mean, to specify locations of the nonzero elements?